# USB Ports In Wrong Mode, How To Use usbmodeswitch?

Tags: 12.04, usb

I haven't had access to my USB ports as media devices for a couple days now. I've been reading and researching everything I can find but I can't find a good guide for usbmodeswtich or usbms that I can decipher.  The USB's are fine for power, but won't support my android phone as a media device, which is killing me because I use adb everyday, and won't support my plug and play mouse any longer.  Not sure what caused the switch, though I think it may be related to the suspend issue I've read about, but the solutions in those threads I read also didn't work. Below is my system information and details.

- System: Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit, Dedicated Machine
- Machine: HP-Pavillion g6 notebook, AMD A6 Quad Core Processor
- USBs used for: Cooling dock, Android Debug Bridge, Wireless Mouse
- Attempted Mod Probe, udev restart, unable to attempt lsusb due to my own lack of knowledge. :)
- Last Attempt Readout:

  ```
  ncandiano@ncandiano-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe -r usbhid && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe usbhid
  ncandiano@ncandiano-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe -r usb-storage
  ncandiano@ncandiano-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe usb-storage
  ncandiano@ncandiano-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo restart udev
  udev start/running, process 2624
  ncandiano@ncandiano-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ lsusb
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0461:4de7 Primax Electronics, Ltd webcam
  ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/usb_modeswitch.1.html) for `usb_modeswitch` I would suggest studying that, it looks helpful. If I recall correctly `usb_modeswitch` is intended for switching the attached USB device, not the port itself. The manpage confirms this. USB by default should work universally and shouldn't keep a specific state when a device is unplugged on a specific port.

I think the issue you are experiencing is more related to the notebook itself and you are on the wrong track, that's why it is so hard to find a good answer. I have heard about dead USB ports on some HP notebooks from colleagues at work, the exact model number and may be product number might help. Something like: g6-1101sg (LS281EA)

If the USB ports are not dead due to some firmware misbehavior you mouse should work as well as `adb`. What Android Phone are you using? Does is really use UMS or MTP/PTP like the Galaxy Nexus? If it uses UMS, it should work just fine, just like plugging a dedicated USB storage stick in and out, no mode switch required. MTP is different because most the software out there is in an immature state.